# AWS How to force the use of interface endpoints in VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Is there any way to force the use of endpoints (interface endpoints or gateway endpoint) in a VPC or AWS account to make sure EC2 instances never use public internet to connect to public facing services in the same region.

If not, is there at least any way to audit / detect which EC2 is communication with a public facing service over the public internet ?

Comment: Could you please clarify your actual goal? Are you wanting to save money, or improve security? Are you wanting to do this for connecting to AWS services, or for connecting with any "public facing service over the public internet" even outside of AWS (eg Facebook)?

Comment: Why would the instances have internet access in the first place if this is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Gateway endpoint, the way to force the use of the endpoint across all the VPC is to associate it with all the VPC route tables.

If you are using an Interface endpoint, the way to force the usage of that endpoint across all the VPC is to override the public DNS record for that service with a Route53 Private Hosted Zone. If we use the EC2 service and the Ireland region as an example:

- You would create a Route53 Private Hosted Zone with the name ***ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com***
- Then you would create an A (Alias) record that points to the VPC EC2 Interface endpoint resource